# Commands to get the metrics of YARN container's actual memory usage

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have found that a containers actual memory usage stats is being supported by yarn as per this jira ticket ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2984). I'd like to know if given an application id can we get the list of memory usages of the containers assigned to that job using any yarn commands ?

Comment: You mean through YARN CLI (Command Line Interface)? You want to access this information through YARN CLI, right?

Comment: Primarily Yes and if any other alternatives which yarn provides are also good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Hadoop 2.7.0.

**CLI:**

The YARN CLI does not expose the memory metrics related to a container.

You can query the status of a container using : `yarn container -status <Container ID>` command.

For e.g. when I executed this command, I got the following output:

```
CMD PROMPT>yarn container -status container_e55_1451819646302_0001_01_000007

Container Report :
        Container-Id : container_e55_1451819646302_0001_01_000007
        Start-Time : 1451909358911
        Finish-Time : 0
        State : RUNNING
        LOG-URL : http://mballur.myorg.com:50060/node/containerlogs/container_e55_1451819646302_0001_01_000007/mballur
        Host : mballur.myorg.com:45454
        NodeHttpAddress : http://mballur.myorg.com:50060
        Diagnostics : null
```

The container report contains (This does not contain any memory related information):

- Container-Id: ID of the container
- Start-Time: Start time for the container
- Finish-Time: Finish time for the conataine. Zero, if the container is still running
- State: State of the container
- LOG-URL: Log URL of the container
- Host: The node ID, where the container is running
- NodeHttpAddress: HTTP address of the container
- Diagnostics: Any diagnostics information.

**UI:**

But, in the UI, when you open the page for a particular container, you will see the following details:

[image: Container Details]

The UI contains **Resource:** information for the container. There you can see the memory and CPU usage (1228 memory, 1 VCores)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Just one more query is that : Is the memory shown in the UI the realtime consumption of the container or anything else ?

Comment: Yes. This is mainly determined by these properties: mapreduce.map.memory.mb and mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. A few more things on my mind : What would be the case if it's not a map-reduce job like a distributed shell or spark etc. Also I see that the memory has always been constant through out the execution of the job, which makes me feel whether it's actually a real time.

Comment: Sorry, I have not used Spark. But, I am sure there will be a similar settings available for Spark jobs. Each Application can have its own custom settings which can be used for determining the size of a container. This memory is the total physical memory allocated to the container (in my case 1228 MB). Please see the blog here, which explains: http://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/. Check the section "Configuring MapReduce 2".

Comment: The way you find this page is: `application -> attempt -> container`, and not `application -> ApplicationMaster`